# grep -l stil show path to file

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am writing a script to search all files from a directory/root based on a keyword input.

```
echo "Enter keyword"
read key
grep -r -l . -e "$key"
```

If I search for `"hei"`, which I know is located in a file called `mem.c`, it prints `/folder/mem.c`, and not only the filename. Do I have some wrong arguments or is it supposed to be like that?

Additional question, is there a way to store these filenames, and copy them into another directory if there is a match in the keyword? Or maybe it is possible to loop through the files found with `grep`?

Comment: Better ask one single question per post. If you want to copy the matching files somewhere, you will need their path, not just their base name. And do you want to reproduce the same hierarchy of sub-directories at destination or do you want to copy all files in the same destination directory? If the latter you will also take care of cases where several files with the same name, but in different sub-directories, match. What would you do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what `grep -l` does: print the path of matching files. If you want to print only the base name of the files you can pipe the result to some command that does that. Example:

```
grep -rlZ "$key" . | xargs -0 -n1 basename
```

Storing the file names in a file is just a matter of redirection:

```
grep -rlZ "$key" . | xargs -0 -n1 basename > mylist.txt
```

To copy the matching files somewhere you will need their path, not just their base name. Assuming **you want to copy them all in the same `destdir` directory** and **you have no name conflicts**, you could use `find`:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l "$key" {} \; -exec cp -f {} destdir \;
```